# Bacon.js "splitting" an event containing an array into multiple events for each element

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, bacon.js

I've recently discovered Bacon.js and have been tinkering but struggling with an issue.

I have an event stream `results` for recent GitHub users returned from an AJAX request. Each result event is as an array of user objects, e.g., `[{ id: 1, login: 'somlor' }, { id: 2, login: 'raimohanska' }, ...]`

**QUESTION:** I'd like create a new `users` event stream that feeds from result events and returns the actual user objects as individual events. Is this possible?

**Here is my code for the result stream, this is working as expected:**

```
// get some recent github users
var ajaxStream = function() {
  var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  var url = 'https://api.github.com/users?since=' + randomOffset;
  return Bacon.fromPromise($.ajax(url));
}

// refresh click stream, start as true to trigger initial ajax call
var refresh = $('a.refresh').asEventStream('click')
                            .map(true)
                            .startWith(true);

// latest results stream. each event is an array of user objects.
var results = refresh.flatMapLatest(ajaxStream);
```

**This is not working.** It creates a single event stream for each `results` array. I want it to "split" each `results` array into a new event for each user object in that array.

```
// stream of individual users created from each result event array
var users = results.map(function(e) { return new Bacon.fromArray(e); });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sean

**UPDATE:**
This is what I was looking for:

```
var users = results.flatMap(Bacon.fromArray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you need to use .flatMap to create the stream.

```
results.flatMap(Bacon.fromArray).onValue(function(v){ console.log(v) });
```

Comment: This is great, thank you @jjuutila. I think then to convert this to a new stream I could do `var users = new Bacon.Bus();` then `results.flatMap(Bacon.fromArray).onValue(function(v) { users.push(v); });`

Comment: I think you don't need that extra Bus because the flatMap produces a new stream.